# Generating Reports with Python: PDF or HTML to PDF

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Using `maptplotlib` I have created 9 graphs which are combined in to a single pdf using the command `savefig`.  However I need to be able to show the statistical analysis below each plot with `.describe()`.  What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas has the possibility to include a table with a plot. See the `table` kwarg to `pandas.DataFrame.plot`. See the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/visualization.html#visualization-table

Comment: This looks like a good option...Is there a way to unstack the table so that only the statistics for one of my columns is being displayed horizontally from `.describe()`

Comment: It's a `pd.DataFrame` so you can manipulate it with the usual methods and slicer, e.g. `df.describe()[["column1","column2"]]`.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple possibilities:

- http://pbpython.com/pdf-reports.html
- http://gael-varoquaux.info/computers/pyreport/
- https://github.com/JanSchulz/knitpy

For the last, have a look at https://github.com/JanSchulz/knitpy/tree/master/examples, the docx, pdf and html versions were generated from the `.pymd` source. The example includes both `pandas.DataFrame`s and matplotlib figures.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of knitpy