# Python - create mulitpage document with PDFs and DataFrames

Tags: python, pdf

I've written a script that generates several DataFrames and several figures as PDF-files (generated by matplotlib as separate pdf-files).

I want to merge these DataFrames and pdf-files into one document, preferably a mulitpage PDF, for sharing with colleagues.

Anyone who knows how to do this? I've tried to install PyPDF2, but the strict IT policies of my company prevent this...

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: To confirm, you want to mix both textual tables and graphics into a single document, and you can only use `pandas` and `matplotlib`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29414980/1304161

Comment: Yes, want to combine bot figures and tables into a single document. Preferably pdf, but I'm also looking into other alternatives.

Comment: Yes, I need to combine both figures and tables into one document. Preferably pdf, but I'm also looking into other alternatives (html, .doc etc.). The case is not that I just can use pandas and matplotlib, we have a lot of other possibilities. But not PyPdf2...

Comment: Thanks @Phlya - that looks like a possible sollution for me!