# Which is the best way to make a report in PDF with more than 100 plots with Python?

Tags: python, pandas, pdf, matplotlib, report

I need to have a report in PDF with a lot of plots. Most of them will be created with matplotlib within a loop, but I would need also to include pandas plots and dataframes (the whole view) and seaborn plots. Right now I have explored the following solutions:

- PythonTex. I have already used it for other projects, but it would consume a lot of time because you have to write \pythontexprint for each plot you want to display.
- Use `savefig` command in every iteration of the loop and save all the plots as image for inserting all in Latex later. That would be very time consuming choice too. Other option is with that command save the plots as pdf and then merge all the pdfs. That would create an ugly report since the plots are not going to fit the whole page.
- Use RStudio with reticulate for creating a Markdown report. The problem here is that I would need to learn reticulate functionality, thus spending time.
- As far as I know, PyPDF does not fit my needs.
- Create a jupyter notebook and then try to export it to a PDF. Once again, I do not know how to use jupyter notebook and I read that I would have to convert first to html and then to pdf.
- Solutions from here: [Generating Reports with Python: PDF or HTML to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29414060/generating-reports-with-python-pdf-or-html-to-pdf?rq=1) However, the question is from three years ago and it might better options nowadays.

So my question is the following: is there any easy and quick way of getting all those plots (if it is along the code which generates them even better) in a PDF with a decent aspect?

Comment: It looks like this question is better suited for [software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My recommendation would be to use matplotlibs `savefig` to a `BytesIO` buffer (or save buffers to a list or similar data structure for 100). Then you can use those image buffers to insert the image into a pdf using a library like `reportlab` (website [here](https://www.reportlab.com/) and docs [here](https://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf)). I regularly use this approach to create PowerPoint documents using `python-pptx` library but also verified it via PDF with `reportlab`. `reportlab` library is very powerful and a bit "low level" so there might be a little learning curve getting started but it surely meets your needs. There is a simple getting started tutorial [here](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/08/a-simple-step-by-step-reportlab-tutorial/). reportlab is BSD license and available on pip and conda.

Anyways my code snippet looks like this.
Sorry its a bit long but my code has some helper functions to print text and dummy images. You should be able to copy/paste it directly.

The code will yield a PDF that looks like this [image]

```
import io

from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph, Spacer, Image
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
from reportlab.lib.units import inch

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def plot_hist():
    """ Create a sample histogram plot and return a bytesio buffer with plot

    Returns
    -------
    BytesIO : in memory buffer with plot image, can be passed to reportlab or elsewhere
    """    
    # from https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_masked.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-scatter-masked-py
    plt.figure(figsize=(7, 2.25))

    N = 100
    r0 = 0.6
    x = 0.9 * np.random.rand(N)
    y = 0.9 * np.random.rand(N)
    area = (20 * np.random.rand(N))**2  # 0 to 10 point radii
    c = np.sqrt(area)
    r = np.sqrt(x * x + y * y)
    area1 = np.ma.masked_where(r < r0, area)
    area2 = np.ma.masked_where(r >= r0, area)
    plt.scatter(x, y, s=area1, marker='^', c=c)
    plt.scatter(x, y, s=area2, marker='o', c=c)
    # Show the boundary between the regions:
    theta = np.arange(0, np.pi / 2, 0.01)
    plt.plot(r0 * np.cos(theta), r0 * np.sin(theta))

    # create buffer and save image to buffer
    # dpi should match the dpi of your PDF, I think 300 is typical otherwise it won't pretty well
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    plt.savefig(buf, format='png', dpi=300)
    buf.seek(0)
    # you'll want to close the figure once its saved to buffer
    plt.close()

    return buf

def add_text(text, style="Normal", fontsize=12):
    """ Adds text with some spacing around it to  PDF report 

    Parameters
    ----------
    text : str
        The string to print to PDF

    style : str
        The reportlab style

    fontsize : int
        The fontsize for the text
    """
    Story.append(Spacer(1, 12))
    ptext = "<font size={}>{}</font>".format(fontsize, text)
    Story.append(Paragraph(ptext, styles[style]))
    Story.append(Spacer(1, 12))

# Use basic styles and the SimpleDocTemplate to get started with reportlab
styles=getSampleStyleSheet()
doc = SimpleDocTemplate("form_letter.pdf",pagesize=letter,
                        rightMargin=inch/2,leftMargin=inch/2,
                        topMargin=72,bottomMargin=18)

# The "story" just holds "instructions" on how to build the PDF
Story=[]

add_text("My Report", style="Heading1", fontsize=24)

# See plot_hist for information on how to get BytesIO object of matplotlib plot
# This code uses reportlab Image function to add and valid PIL input to the report
image_buffer1 = plot_hist()
im = Image(image_buffer1, 7*inch, 2.25*inch)
Story.append(im)

add_text("This text explains something about the chart.")

image_buffer2 = plot_hist()
im = Image(image_buffer2, 7*inch, 2.25*inch)
Story.append(im)

add_text("This text explains something else about another chart chart.")

# This command will actually build the PDF
doc.build(Story)

# should close open buffers, can use a "with" statement in python to do this for you
# if that works better
image_buffer1.close()
image_buffer2.close()
```